# Textbox counter with another textbox counter

Tags: c#, textbox, counter

I have two textboxes "SerialNumber" and "SerialExtension". SerialNumber is auto generated starting with 1, which increases each time I click the "Add" button. The SerialExtension textbox has to have A,B, C,etc, concatenated with the SerialNumber value dispalyed each time I click the "Display" button. For that I gave a char counter. But each time the SerialNumber increases, my char counter does not reset from 'A'. Can anyone help me out? Code in C# please.

```
private static int counter = 1;
static char a = 'A';
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
           txtSerialNo.Text = counter.ToString("0");
     }

protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {
          counter++;
        txtSerialNo.Text = counter.ToString("0");
     }

protected void btnDisplay_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {
          txtSerialextension.Text = txtSerialNo.Text + a.ToString();
          a++;
     }
```

Comment: Where is the code, how can the problem be assessed without the code here !

Comment: i was hoping u could give me the code.....

Comment: Since this seems to be homework related, it's a good idea that you show what you have so far, and we can give you pointers on how to proceed. You will learn a lot more that way.

Comment: Can you explain what do you mean by reset ? what is the desired output .. could if you could put that down on the question

Comment: It is your homework. How do you expect to learn if you don't at least TRY writing the code (and showing us your workings) so that we can show you where you went wrong.

Comment: "Code in C# please." Would you like a cup of coffee with it Sir ?

Comment: im sorry for asking too much...but i could use the help!!!

Comment: the problem with my above code is that when i stop at 1G and increment the serialnumber to 2, the serialextension starts from 2G and not 2A.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason that `a` does not start over with the value `'A'` is that you will need to reassign that to `a` every time that it should be reset; there is no way for the program code to *guess* when this should happen. In your case, you want that to happen when you click `btnAdd`, so you need to add code for this in the click event handler for that button:

```
protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    a = 'A'; // reset a to the value 'A'
    counter++;
    txtSerialNo.Text = counter.ToString("0");
}
```

Comment: this wont work as "a" will initialize as "A" with each add click.

Comment: i need to reset the char counter with each change in the SerialNo textbox.

Comment: @RAHUL: that is how I interpreted the desired behavior (*"But each time the SerialNumber increases, my char counter does not reset from 'A'."*). When you click the Add button, the counter increases (thus the serial number increases), so `a` should be reset to `'A'`. If that is not correct, please update the question so it clearly describes the desired behavior.

Comment: yes...what u mentioned above, that is what i need.

Comment: @RAHUL: I tested this out; if you update `btnAdd_Click` as suggested in my answer, the code will behave as you expect (note that `txtSerialextension` is not being automatically updated when you click the `Add` button, but that is also not mentioned in your question).

Answer (score 1):

How to assign values in C#:
[= Operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbkb459w%28v=VS.100%29.aspx), works for `char` as well.